# Compare two arrays of objects and get the objects based on ids

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays of objects. One has an id property with a list of ids and the second has an object with a unique id property. I want to filter the ids in the second array with the first list and get the data.

```js
const data1 = [{
  name: 'A',
  ids: [1, 2, 3]
}, {
  name: 'B',
  ids: [4, 5, 6]
}, {
  name: 'C',
  ids: [7, 8, 9]
}]

const data2 = [{
    id: 1,
    color: 'red'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    color: 'black'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    color: 'blue'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    color: 'yellow'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    color: 'green'
  }, {
    id: 6,
    color: 'pink'
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    color: 'orange'
  }, {
    id: 8,
    color: 'white'
  }, {
    id: 9,
    color: 'teal'
  }
]

const arrayToObject = (array) =>
  array.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item
    return obj
  }, {})

console.log(arrayToObject(data2))

const newData = data1.map(item => {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    data: item.ids.map(i => arrayToObject(data2)[i])
  }
})

console.log(newData)
```

Expected Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "A",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "color": "red"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "color": "black"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "color": "blue"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "color": "yellow"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "color": "green"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "color": "pink"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 7,
        "color": "orange"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "color": "white"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "color": "teal"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I did manage to achieve this, but I guess there might be a better clean and performant solution. Please advice me on that.

P.S: I am also open to using lodash.

Comment: Since the second object's ids are unique. Why not convert it to dictionary first, like `{1:"red", 2:"black", 3:"blue"}` then loop the array in first object.

Comment: I don't see any filtering going on. It looks like you just replaced the `ids` property with `data`, containing a join of the ids and `data2` arrays.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: @Frank 's suggestion to use a map cuts this from a O(n^2) to O(n) problem, aside from that what you're doing is fine.

Comment: @Frank The data is being given to me by an external API.

Comment: @a2441918 no matter it's trivial to convert it to a map yourself.

Comment: @Frank I updated the OP. Is this a better solution?

Comment: That's the idea, but what you did is like create a new dictionary everytime.. You should just do it once, sth like `const data3 = data2.reduce((obj, item) => {
    obj[item.id] = item
    return obj
  }, {})
`

Comment: Cool. Thanks @Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got to the standard method:

1. Create a dictionary or a Map by `id`
2. Iterate `data1` with `Array.map()`
3. Take the `ids` and take the items from the dictionary

You can shorten the code a bit using lodash:

1. Create a dictionary using [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#keyBy)
2. Take the items from the dictionary using [`_.at()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#at)

```js
const data1 = [{"name":"A","ids":[1,2,3]},{"name":"B","ids":[4,5,6]},{"name":"C","ids":[7,8,9]}]
const data2 = [{"id":1,"color":"red"},{"id":2,"color":"black"},{"id":3,"color":"blue"},{"id":4,"color":"yellow"},{"id":5,"color":"green"},{"id":6,"color":"pink"},{"id":7,"color":"orange"},{"id":8,"color":"white"},{"id":9,"color":"teal"}]

// create the dictionary
const dict = _.keyBy(data2, 'id')

// get the items from the dictionary
const newData = data1.map(({ ids, ...item }) => ({ ...item, data: _.at(dict, ids) }))

console.log(newData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-90vH1Z83AJY9DmlWa8WkjkV79yfS2n2Oxhsi2dZbIv0nC4E6m5AbH8Nh156kkM7JePmqD6tcZsfad1ueoaovww==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```